# Strange behaviour of << (as at least seems to me)

Tags: c++, cout

I can't realize how could it be possible to print a string this way without any complaint by the compiler:

```
std::cout << "Hello " "World!";
```

In fact, the above line works exactly like:

```
std::cout << "Hello " << "World!";
```

Is there an explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: Actually, it behaves exactly like `std::cout << "Hello World!";` The second version above calls the stream inserter **twice**, while the first calls it **once**.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Adjacent literal tokens are concatenated automatically, it's part of the standard.

#### 2.1 Phases of translation [lex.phases]

> 6) Adjacent <del>ordinary string</del> literal tokens are concatenated. <del>Adjacent wide string literal tokens are concatenated.</del>

(C++03)

Comment: Thanks... I'm moving from Java to C++... Never heard about something like this before.

Comment: So it is the same for integer literals:
'int i = 123 456 789; // int i = 123456789;

Comment: @maurizeio what's an integer literal?

Comment: @Luchian: if that's not a trick question, then integer literals are defined in 2.13.1 of the C++03 standard. Why have you crossed out some of the text? By doing so you incorrectly suggest that literal tokens other than string literals are concatenated.

Comment: I thought this also could be right... but it's not.
`int i = 123 456 789;
cout << i; // will print 123456789`

Comment: @SteveJessop I didn't treat it as a trick question, I've never heard of integer literals before. Also, those lines are crossed out in my version of the standard, that's why I also crossed them out here.

Comment: @Luchian: maybe the reason you haven't heard the term is just that the thing that in C++ is called an "integer literal" is called in C an "integer constant", not a "literal" at all.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore - what you're looking at is your version of **not the standard**; that's why things are crossed out. The C++03 version is what you quoted, including the text that you show as crossed out; the C++11 version says "Adjacent string literal tokens are concatenated." That change was made because of the proliferation of string literal token types; the details of concatenation are now covered in [lex.string].

Comment: @PeteBecker yes, it's a draft (and already noted that it's a C++03 one). I thought the crossed out parts are changes.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore - the crossed out parts mark changes from the previous draft. They don't tell you what ended up in the final version, or even in the next draft.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, literals tokens can be concatenated thusly:

```
const char* thingy = "Hello" "World";
```

`"Hello"` and `"World`" are each a literal token.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behavior of the strings. In the first line specified strings are concatenated by compiler automatically. As sample you can specify also multiline to avoid very long line.

```
const char *strLine = "line 1 "
                      "line 1 "
                      "line 2 ";
```

And it will work OK. The second line is cleared, specified another line for output.